# Chinese characters instead of text into the metadata called "Producer"

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, metadata, pdf-manipulation

I have a problem when I edit the metadata of a pdf with iTextSharp.
I save a word document in pdf with Word. The field called "Producer" is filled by word with the text "Microsoft Word 210". After, I edit the metadata with ITextSharp and iTextSharp tries to edit this field in order to add the text "modified using iTextSharp 4.1.6".

The result is `Producer(þÿMicrosoft® Word 2010; modified using iTextSharp 4.1.6 by 1T3XT)`. In adobe reader, the field PDF Producer in document properties shows chinese characters.

Adobe can read the field if I remove manually the characters `þÿ`.

Do you know why I have this problem ?
What can I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say Hello :)

Comment: This looks like a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that needs to be omitted / removed.

Comment: Comparing the source for 4.1.6 with the current 5.5.0 it appears this has been addressed in newer versions

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, this works with iText 2.1.7. It is Java code, but probably works too for C#.

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfString;

public class AppTest {

    @Test
    public void testApp() throws Exception {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(AppTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/msword2010.pdf"));

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("target", "modified_msword2010.pdf"));
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fos, '\0', true);

        PdfDictionary infoDict = stamper.getReader().getTrailer().getAsDict(PdfName.INFO);
        String producerCleaned = null;

        if (infoDict != null) {
            PdfString producer = (PdfString) infoDict.get(PdfName.PRODUCER);
            if (producer != null) {
                producerCleaned = producer.toUnicodeString();
                PdfString cleanStrObj = new PdfString(producerCleaned);
                infoDict.put(PdfName.PRODUCER, cleanStrObj);
            }
        }

        stamper.close();
    }
}
```